# How to check any of the list of words present in the string?

Tags: java, java-8

I have list of words which i need to check if any of the words in list is present in string or not but word in the string can be in any format let say i have list of words `{:carloan:,creditcard}` but in string it can be like `car-loan` or `carloan` or `:carloan` in any of this formats.

I am using lambda function in java to find the any near match but its not working like below:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(":carloan:")
list.add(":creditcard:")
String inputString = "i want carloan"
boolean match = list.stream().anyMatch(s -> inputString.contains(s));
```

But above method is giving boolean `true` only if the substring is **matching exactly** same with the word in the list.

Is there way i can give true even if it match partially let say the user entered `car-loan` but in list it's like `:carloan:` i don't want to use iterate over a list and do matching. Please suggest me way i can do using lambda function in java.

Comment: Get rid of the colons... Either in the list or during the stream operation. Why have you added them to the list with these colons?

Comment: @deHaar its mandatory to have colons as per requirements that's why i am keeping them, even i tried removing the colons but still its not working

Comment: It's not possible to do this kind of "fuzzy" matching without data science stuff. If you need to match `car-loan` or `carloan` or `:carloan` - your best bet is to have all possible variation listed and use regex as suggested in answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex approach here:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("carloan");
list.add("creditcard");

String regex = ".*(?:" + String.join("|", list) + ").*";
String input = "I am looking for a carloan or creditcard";
if (input.matches(regex)) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

Some possible changes you might want to make to the above would be to add word boundaries around the alternation.  That is, you might want to use this regex pattern:

```
.*\b(?:carloan|creditcard)\b.*
```

This would avoid matching e.g. `carloans` when you really want to exactly match only the singular `carloan`.

**Edit:**

Here is a version using regex closer to your original starting point:

```
boolean result = list.stream().anyMatch(s -> input.matches(".*\\b" + s + "\\b.*"));
if (result) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

We can stream your list of terms, and then assert whether the input string matches any term using regex.  But note that this approach means calling `String#matches` N times, for a list of N terms, while the above approach just makes a single call to that API.  I would bet on the alternation approach being more efficient here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim is it possible to do this using lambda function instead of regex?

Comment: @user13906258, I believe regex is best to use here. Do not unnecessarily put lambda and stream in everything.

Comment: @user13906258 Sure, check the edit in my answer.  You could also stream the terms, as you are doing, but use `String#matches` with regex inside the call to `anyMatch()`.

Comment: This answer assumes that the OP can simply remove the colons. But if the OP removes the colons, even the code of the question does its job.

Comment: @Holger I was also curious about the colons, and maybe the assignment question has some content which is missing in the OP's description above.